# Make the Recommend Deletion, Reject Edit "dialogs" moveable

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, user-experience

Contrarily to most "dialogs" (or floaty, or... I don't know what's the exact term) on StackOverflow (e.g. flag a post, close a post, etc), the Recommend Deletion and the Reject Edit dialogs can't be moved around.

This is annoying when you want to check the question / answer you're recommending for deletion as you want to flag it appropriately. The same goes for the Reject Edit dialog.

This is also annoying because they're different from the user experience one is used to from most (all?) the other dialogs.

Could this be fixed?

For reference, here is a screenshot of the Recommend Deletion dialog:
[image: Stack Overlfow Recommend Deletion Dialog]

And the Reject Edit dialog
[image: Stack Overflow Reject Edit Dialog]

Comment: You need to be able to look at the couple of lines of text they've posted as an answer? Did you forget what reason you were going to Recommend Deletion to begin with? I honestly don't see why this particular dialog box would need to be draggable, but I support this for consistency's sake.